# Constructor of a class within a template class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Created a generic tree, trying to use it with a custom class which holds a int value and an int array.

After trying to initialize the array in few different ways, none seem to go through to the main function.
constructor of node class:

```
class ArrNode
{
    int id;
    int* arr;
    int length;
    public:
    ArrNode(int a, int b)
   {
       id = a;
       length = b;
       arr = new int[length]();
   }
    ~ArrNode()
    {
        if(arr != nullptr)
            delete arr;
    }
    int getArrVal(int i) const
    {
        return this->arr[i];
    }
};
```

template class:

```
template <class T>
class AvlTree
{
    private:
    T val;
    AvlTree *left;
    AvlTree *right;
    int height;
    public:
    AvlTree(ArrNode t) : val(t) {}
    T getVal()
    {
        return this->val;
    }
```

main function:

```
ArrNode t(5,3) //random numbers
AvlTree<ArrNode> a(t);
```

Assume there are working get functions for both the classes, i've tried:

1. using a init list
2. send a built up node into the the tree (the one pasted here)
3. send int values and building up the node inside the tree constructor

all which worked in the scope of the function, but after returning to the main function the array was not initialized to zeroes as expected.

Note - trying not to use any of the std containers

Comment: `ArrNode` has a pointer as member, not an array. Use `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: hey, forgot to add i'm not allowed to use any of the std containers, will edit the question

Comment: please include a [mcve] of your code in the quesiton. The `ArrNode` you did post misses some important stuff (see rule of 3/5), whether this is only because you omitted it here is unclear

Comment: Alright, i wanted to make it easier to read so i tried to omit as much as possible, created a reproducible example

Comment: `if(arr != nullptr)` is unneeded in destructor, but you should call `delete[]` instead.

Comment: *"I'm not allowed to use any of the std containers"*, so write your own simplified version.

Comment: @Jarod42 i'm not asking for anyone to write an std or write my code, just looking for the correct syntax to make it work

Comment: if you need a dynamically sized array then you need a dynamically sized array not a pointer. Write a `MyDynamicArray` and use that if it cannot be `std::vector`. Currently you are trying to implement a dynamic array inside a node type, thats too much for one type. Read about the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (and don't miss the part: "Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively with ownership")

Answer (score 0):

So after further testing and help here, the mistake was doing not following the rule of 3, after implementing the copy assignment operator it worked as intended